# Scala reverse list implementation

Tags: algorithm, scala, reverse

Want to clarify, why scala implemented reverse list in this way

```
 override def reverse: List[A] = {
    var result: List[A] = Nil
    var these = this
    while (!these.isEmpty) {
      result = these.head :: result
      these = these.tail
    }
    result
  }
```

Why could not implement in this way ?

```
  @tailrec
  private def reverseRec[A](init: List[A], res: List[A]): List[A] = {
    if(init.isEmpty) return res
    reverseRec[A](init.tail, init.head :: res)
  }
```

Any additional implementation of reverse with immutable states ?

Comment: It's most likely an optimisation. All that matters is that no side effects are observable outside the implementation of `reverse`.

Comment: Agree with @Jubobs. Most of the Scala collection methods are implemented in an imperative performance benefits.

Comment: Also, don't use `return` here, since it's implemented with exceptions. There's no need in your case - a simple if/else will do.

Comment: The second way will be changed to a while loop similar to the first, by the compiler. That's what happens with tail recursion, to avoid stack overflow. I suppose they just wanted to be explicit, but the performance should be the same.

Answer (score -1):

```
def reverseList[A](list: List[A]): List[A] = list match {
  case Nil => Nil
  case head :: tail => reverseList(tail) ::: List(head)
}
```

Comment: Remember that Stack Overflow isn't just intended to solve the immediate problem, but also to help future readers find solutions to similar problems, which requires understanding the underlying code. This is especially important for members of our community who are beginners, and not familiar with the syntax. Given that, **can you [edit] your answer to include an explanation of what you're doing** and why you believe it is the best approach?